# Have you read Diophantus? What did you get out of it?

Tags: soft-question, diophantine-equations

I'm starting to read Sir Thomas L. Heath's translation of Diophantus:

[Diophantus Of Alexandria: A Study In The History Of Greek Algebra](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.154147)

My motivation is to understand more of Fermat's thinking. Also in this volume are "some of the more remarkable solutions of difficult Diophantine problems" by Euler.

Just wondering other people's experience in reading Diophantus, the level of difficulty and what it taught them or how it relates to other mathematics.

Comment: Well, Fermat read Diophantus, so that's my motivation...

Comment: You are also reading Diophantus, so this you have in common with Fermat then. Actually, Euler's papers are really interesting, too.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1401110/nonlinear-system-diophantus

Comment: Diophantus in his book devotes lots of attention to systems of nonlinear equations. In the modern theory of numbers, this is all not paid attention. This area is actually not considered by anyone.  The fact that this is a very difficult task.  Although some systems can be solved.